# Dictionary lookup using a variable

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, compare

Can a dictionary of type string and CheckBox be parsed by a variable string in such a way that should the variable string find a dictionary entry that matches it, it will set the corresponding checkbox to true?

Comment: Can you give an example of a variable string you would use? I'm not familiar with the term in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using following code.
Let's say you have `myDictionary<string, CheckBox>` and a string `stringToCheck` which contains that value you want to find in the dictionary
You can do something like this

```
string stringToCheck = "something";

if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(stringToCheck))
{
    myDictionary[stringToCheck].Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is way easier than I originally thought!

Comment: if you use TryGetValue you can check the presence of the key and get the associated value with a single instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Is Dictionary.ContainsValue what you are looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking: I have a Dictionary.  I want to set the corresponding checkbox to true for a given string.  That can be accomplished by the following

```
Dictionary<string, CheckBox> dictionary = <elided>;
CheckBox checkBox = dictionary[valueToSearch];
checkBox.Checked = true;
```

Comment: He says "should the variable string find a dictionary entry that matches it" so you should definitely check if the dictionary contains valueToSearch rather than assuming it's always in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TryGetValue to reduce the accesses to the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, CheckBox> aDict;
// your code here
CheckBox tmp;
if (aDict.TryGetValue(stringToSearch, out tmp))
    tmp.Checked = true;
```